# Looping over the last few entries of an array

Tags: javascript, loops

I'm trying to have a `forEach` loop over an array, but only the last few entries.

I'd know how to do this in a for loop, that'd look a bit like this:

```js
var arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]; 

/* This will loop over the last 3 entries */
for(var x = arr.length; x >= 7; x--){
    console.log(arr[x]);
}
```

Would there be any way of achieving the same results in a `forEach` loop?

Comment: No there is absolutely no way that you can do this with a `.forEach()` loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `slice()` and `reverse()` methods and then `forEach()` loop on that new array.

```js
var arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]; 
arr.slice(-3).reverse().forEach(e => console.log(e))
```

Comment: That's actually a pretty smart way of doing this! Thanks!

Comment: note the users output produces undefined, 10, 9, 8 not sure if that is intentional or not

Answer (score 0):

This is how you do it with forEach loop:

```
var arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]; 
arr.forEach((element, index) => {
  if(index>7) console.log(arr[index]);
})
```

Comment: Code dumps are not *useful* answers. Say what you did, and more importantly *why*. But note that you're visiting the entries in the wrong order.

Answer (score 0):

You could take a classic approach by taking the count of the last elements and use it as counter and an offset for the index.

Then loop with `while` by decrementing and checking the counter.

```js
var array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10],
    last = 3,
    offset = array.length - last;
    
while (last--) {
    console.log(array[last + offset]);
}
```